# Replacing a color using -transparency regardless of existing pixel opacity, using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I have a colorful image that has alot of existing transparent background, but also a few blocks of hot pink `rgb(255,0,255)` color I want to additionally become transparent.

I'm doing so like this:

```
convert 0001.png -fuzz 15% -fill transparent -transparent "rgb(255,0,255)" result.png
```

The problem is, because the original image was anti-aliased, there is still a hot pink halo, where it's not matching e.g. `rgba(255,0,255,  50  )` and other partially-transparent values, unless I turn up the `-fuzz` way too high.

So I figured I'd solve the problem like this:

```
convert 0001.png -fuzz 15% -fill transparent
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,0)"
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,64)"
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,128)"
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,192)"
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,255)"
result.png
```

...but the additional calls to `-transparent` with varying levels of opacity don't seem to be having any additional effect.

It is almost as if calls to -transparent truncate my `rgba(255,0,255,128)` to `rgb(255,0,255)` before doing match (although `-fuzz` still looks at opacity, it seems to always do so starting from 255, not from the opacity I pass into `-transparent`).

How can I replace all examples of the color `RGB(255,0,255)`, regardless of the pixel's pre-existing alpha?

This is the image I'm using:

[image]

This is what I'm being left with and I want to remove: (magnified and given white background for ease of seeing)
[image]

Comment: Are those dashed pink lines in the final image what you want to get rid of?

Comment: Yes, I want the dashed pink removed. The call to `-transparent` is only getting rid of the fully opaque pink, not the semi-opaque pink, when the opacity falls below the '-fuzz' threshold, but turning up the fuzz makes `-transparent` also remove colors that aren't pink.

Comment: look at background removal https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove. - Or a -floodfill with appropriate fuzz might do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...but the additional calls to `-transparent` with varying levels of opacity don't seem to be having any additional effect.

In `rgba(R,G,B,A)` the `A` is [from `0` (fully transparent) to `1` (fully opaque)](https://imagemagick.org/script/color.php), not from `0` to `255`. Your attempt can be fixed like this:

```
convert 0001.png -fuzz 15% -fill transparent \
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,0)" \
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,0.25)" \
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,0.5)" \
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,0.75)" \
-transparent "rgba(255,0,255,1)" \
result.png
```

This is the result:

[image: result, fuzz 15%]

I don't know if it's *the* best solution. At least it shows your idea with multiple `-transparent` wasn't bad, you just got the range of opacity wrong.

The above result is not perfect, there are some pinkish remnants where pink has been blended with other (opaque) colors. With `-fuzz 35%` it looks better in this aspect:

[image: result, fuzz 35%]

but the edges lose their softness.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I get tripped up by the 255 vs 1.0 thing quite alot in other domains; I should've realized that was the problem. =/